# Any way I can run custom LINQ during debug / breakpoint in VS2010 or otherwise?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010

I often need to get some numbers from collections while I am debugging.

What I currently have to do is to write 'test' lines of code just to check an idea and once i get the answer i need to write anoter test code check another idea which derived from the answer. it seems real stupid to me.

I was wondering if there exists a magic tool which enables using collection on breakpoint so I can write LINQ extensions on it immediately?

Comment: I think LinqPad, the paid version - http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: you can have conditions on breakpoints, not sure if you can inject LINQ in there because usually the condition has to return a bool. ther option is to write your LINQ in a Watch and it will be available and evaluated in the debugger.

Comment: Davide, that what exactly I need - to write linq and get it evaluated in the debugger. it doesnt work in VS.... this is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ABCDAC4-AFFE-4AE8-822C-B662264DEA65) to let you use LINQ in the immediate window.  I've never used it, so not sure how well it works.

And like I said in the comment, check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: Martin this project you posted the link to is exactly what I need. but unfortunately the guy abandoned it in 2008 soon it was published.... it seems not a lot of people need it.

Comment: Linqpad - I know abt it - it is not connected to VS. if you need to manipulate with LINQ to SQL - thats cool (either I would probably use SQl studio rather). But my problem - I need to use my own collections which are coming from text and binary files.